# File cannot be opened/corrupted after writing sucessfully using Java NIO file channel

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer, filechannel

i have the following code which runs without error and writes the output file successfully. However, i am not able to open the output file. it always prompts me an error saying "word found unreadable content"

anyone can advise if there is anything wrong with my code?

```
`File inputf = new File("C:\\Appl\\CM table deployment.docx");
File outputf = new File("C:\\Appl\\CM table deployment1.docx");

RandomAccessFile infile = new RandomAccessFile(inputf, "r");
RandomAccessFile outfile = new RandomAccessFile(outputf, "rw");
FileChannel inChannel = infile.getChannel();
FileChannel outChannel = outfile.getChannel();


ByteBuffer inbuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024*64);

    long position = 0;

    System.out.println("inChannel.size(): " + inChannel.size());        

    while(inChannel.read(inbuffer) > 0)
              {
                  inbuffer.flip();
                  ByteBuffer outbuffer;

                  if(position+inbuffer.capacity()<inChannel.size())
                         outbuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024*64);

                  else 
                         outbuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int)(inChannel.size()-position+1));

                  outbuffer.put(inbuffer.get());

                  while (outbuffer.hasRemaining()){

                        outChannel.write(outbuffer, position);

                        if(position+inbuffer.capacity()<inChannel.size()){
                              position = position + inbuffer.capacity();
                              System.out.println("next position : "+ position);
                        }
                        else{
                              position = position+1;
                              System.out.println("next position : "+ position);
                        }

                 }     



     outbuffer.clear();
              inbuffer.clear(); // do something with the data and clear/compact it.
          }

          inChannel.close();
          outChannel.close();
          infile.close();
          outfile.close();
`
```

Comment: If you're just trying to copy the file you don't need all this. Have a look at the NIO Tutorial. The standard copy loop is only 4-5 lines of code.

Comment: In fact, if you’re just copying a file, you can use `Files.copy(inputf.toPath(), outputf.toPath())`.  See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29).

Comment: Yes.  I understand there are easier ways to code this Copy but I am copying large files each transaction. Up to 2 gb. That is why I tried to copy chunk by chunk using the byte buffer. Any advice?

Comment: Yes. Don't bother. You can't outsmart standard code. There is no advantage to doing it your way even if it worked, which it doesn't. And you certainly don't need two buffers. This just wastes time and space.

Comment: So will the standard code take care of memory issues for me even if I am copy 2 gb files each time? Do I have to worry abt oom?

Comment: The standard code uses one buffer of a size you choose. That's the only possible memory issue. It goes like this: `while (in.read(buffer) > 0 || buffer.position() > 0) { buffer.flip(); out.write(buffer); buffer.compact(); }.`.